# Constructing result for given word's order and overlapping in Shortest Superstring Problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman, np-hard

For over 3 days I'm trying to solve [Shortest Superstring](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-shortest-superstring/description/) problem and I still can't figure out how can I create resulting string when I know in what order should I use given words and how these words overlaps. I have read many solutions but I really don't understand them indeed.

That's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int cost;
    int next_mask;
    int next_node;

    Node(int cost, int mask, int next_node) : cost(cost), next_mask(mask), next_node(next_node)
    {
    }

    Node() : cost(-1), next_mask(-1), next_node(-1)
    {
    }

    bool is_done() const {
        return cost != -1;
    }
};

// Cost = how many extra characters do I need to fully overlap w2. The characters from w1 are not extra
pair<int, string> get_cost(string const& w1, string const& w2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w1.size(); ++i) {
        string sub = w1.substr(i);
        int overlaps_start = w2.find(sub);
        if (overlaps_start != 0)
            continue;

        int overlapping_count = overlaps_start + sub.size();
        return { w2.size() - overlapping_count, sub };
    }

    return { w2.size(), "" };
}

void solve(vector<vector<int>> const& graph, int current, int mask, vector<vector<Node>>& dp) {
    if (mask == (1 << graph.size()) - 1 || dp[mask][current].is_done())
        return;

    for (int node = 0; node < graph.size(); ++node) {
        int check_state_mask = 1 << node;
        if (mask & check_state_mask)
            continue;

        int node_mask = mask | check_state_mask;
        solve(graph, node, node_mask, dp);
        int sub = graph[current][node] + dp[node_mask][node].cost;

        if (!dp[mask][current].is_done() || sub < dp[mask][current].cost) {
            dp[mask][current].cost = sub;
            dp[mask][current].next_mask = node_mask;
            dp[mask][current].next_node = node;
        }
    }
}

string shortestSuperstring(vector<string>& words) {
    vector<vector<int>> graph(words.size(), vector<int>(words.size()));
    vector<vector<string>> common_parts(words.size(), vector<string>(words.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); ++j) {
            pair<int, string> cost1 = get_cost(words[i], words[j]);
            pair<int, string> cost2 = get_cost(words[j], words[i]);

            graph[i][j] = cost1.first;
            graph[j][i] = cost2.first;

            common_parts[i][j] = cost1.second;
            common_parts[j][i] = cost2.second;
        }
    }

    // dp also tracks the path
    vector<vector<Node>> dp(1 << graph.size(), vector<Node>(graph.size(), Node()));
    solve(graph, 0, 1, dp);

    // We start from node 0 with mask = 1, so the result is at dp[1][0]
    Node parent = dp[1][0];
    int parent_node = 0;
    while (parent.next_node != -1) {
        // What should happen here to build a result???
        cout << parent_node << " : " << parent.next_node << " Common: " << common_parts[parent_node][parent.next_node] << "\n";

        parent_node = parent.next_node;
        parent = dp[parent.next_mask][parent.next_node];
    }

    return "im-too-weak-to-solve-it";
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v{ "catg","ctaagt","gcta","ttca","atgcatc" };
    std::cout << shortestSuperstring(v);
}
```

If you run this code, you will see that for some nodes they may not be common string, and I think that's my problem. When I know where two strings overlaps, I can do some substrings and get the result. But when some strings don't have common part, then I don't know where to insert them, and I can't omit this one because the next one will depend on it and so on.

Theoretically, I could find the best position for it (most overlapping) by looking at current result, but how can I be sure that it won't destroy the result? If I put it on the end or on the beginning, then how can I be sure that there is no better solution?

So how can I construct the result if I know the word's order and how they overlaps?

Comment: You output the words in that order, removing any overlap between adjacent words. If there is no overlap, you just remove nothing.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It doesnt work. After ordering words I get `catgatgcatcgctactaagtttca`, so after removing overlaps I get `catgcatcgctaagttca` which length is equal to 18. The expected string length is 16.

Comment: This means your ordering is incorrect. `solve` is supposed to produce an ordering with the minimal total cost. Your cost is 14 but the correct cost is 12.

Comment: It looks like you always start your path from node 0. This is incorrect. You need to try all starts. The simplest way is to add a fake node with cost of 0 to every other node, and start from this fake node.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Ok, I understand the concept and coded it. It fails for `["gruuz","zjr","uuzj","rfgr"]`. Expected result is `"rfgruuzjr"`, so it means that order is bad. I checked the `get_cost` method and it works fine,  so there is problem with `solve` method. I see something strange - for equal costs, I get results that can have different lengths. When in `solve` method I do `<= sub`, then above case passes, but it causes fail for other test cases. Why? Maybe it's normal behavior and I need to consider 2 possible solutions: one normal and one where the last comes to the beginningof result?

Comment: I think we can consider two solutions because the last one can be normally at the end, or at the beginning because theoretically in graph the last one is immediately before starting node

Comment: "for equal costs, I get results that can have different lengths" Looks like you need to add the length of the first node to the total cost, then your total cost will be the same as the length of the string. Again you can implement this with a fake node at index 0, but now its edges will have nonzero cost which is the length of the destination node.

Comment: 1/2 Ok, so I added parameter to `solve` called `int first_node`. It says which node I visited from the fake node. Later, I check if `mask` is equal to `1 << starting_node` where `starting_node` is the fake node. If yes, it means that I should do recursive call with `node` from `for loop` as the `first_node`. If the first condition failed, I use the same `first_node` so I persist the `first_node` to the end (moment where `mask` is something like `1111`, all nodes visited). There, I can get the cost of going from destination to first node:  `dp[mask][current].cost = graph[current][first_node];`.

Comment: 2/2 It passes the mentioned test case, but brokes the others. That's how it looks: https://pastebin.com/2XpYuJGe

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot debug this for you.

Comment: My point was whether I understood your idea

Comment: Ok, I changed my strategy of evaluating cost. I made my cost equal to overlapping characters and in `solve` I look for the longest result. It works, and the whole idea about `first_node` and nonzero edges of fake node wasnt necessary. At the last node I can return 0, because I don't need to return back to starting node. That was really hard, thank you so much!

Comment: This is definitely another valid way of doing it.